# Spring cloud stream - org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring cloud stream to consume message from a kafka topic.
Spring boot version - 2.7.13

**Spring config:-**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: prj-consumer


spring.cloud.function:
  definition: prjProcessor


spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    input:
      destination: topic-1
      group: group-1
    output:
      destination: topic-out-2
    failureQueue:
      destination: topic-out-fail-2


spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings:
  prjProcessor-in-0: input
  prjProcessor-out-0: output


spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
  brokers: <BROKERS>
  configuration: 
        security:
          protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl:
          mechanism: PLAIN
        
  consumer-properties:
        security:
          protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl:
          mechanism: PLAIN
        


spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings:
  input:
    consumer:
      autoCommitOffset: false
```

The message in kafka topic,

```
[
{"eid":"Prj1","name":"Test Prj","createdBy":"First User","createdOn":"2022-11-11T00:00:00Z","lastModifiedBy":"System User","lastModifiedOn":"2023-07-17T20:22:32.262Z"},
{"eid":"Prj2","name":"Test Prj2","createdBy":"First User","createdOn":"2022-11-11T00:00:00Z","lastModifiedBy":"System User","lastModifiedOn":"2023-07-17T20:22:32.262Z"}
]
```

Getting the error below while consuming this.

```
"message": "Failure during type conversion by org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter@7684a7e5. Will try the next converter.",
  "logger": "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.SmartCompositeMessageConverter",
  
 "class": "org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException",
    "msg": "Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (String)\"{eid=Prj1, name=Test Prj}\"; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (String)\"{id=Prj1, name=Test Prj}}\"; line: 1, column: 3]",
    "stack": [
      "org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:237)",
      "org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.convertFromInternal(ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.java:115)",
      "org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:185)",
      "org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:176)",
      "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.SmartCompositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(SmartCompositeMessageConverter.java:63)",
      "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertInputMessageIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1332)",
      "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertInputIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1091)",
      "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.lambda$convertInputPublisherIfNecessary$24(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1444)",
      "reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)",
      "reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539)",
      "reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335)",
      "reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294)",
      "reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:649)",
```

**Question:-**

The message in the topic is with keys in Double quote, but when it comes here, the format seems to be different and throwing error with one converted and then works with the other converter.

**Spring cloud code:-**

```
public Object fromMessage(Message<?> message, Class<?> targetClass) {
        for (MessageConverter converter : getConverters()) {
            if (!(message.getPayload() instanceof byte[]) && targetClass.isInstance(message.getPayload()) && !(message.getPayload() instanceof Collection<?>)) {
                return message.getPayload();
            }
            try {
                Object result = converter.fromMessage(message, targetClass);
                if (result != null) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                    logger.warn("Failure during type conversion by " + converter + ". Will try the next converter.", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```